# Postman fails to authorize against Slack App

Tags: postman, slack

I'm following the steps described in this [Slack tutorial on authorizing Postman](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/slack-apps-and-postman). When I get to the end and try to request the token from Postman, the Slack OAuth window pops up and I can authorize.

On Postman however, I get an error message:

> Could not complete OAuth 2.0 login.
>   Check Postman Console for more details.

Checking the Postman console shows:

> POST https://slack.com/api/oauth.access
>   bad_client_secret
>   Error

If checked and double checked, and I'm sure I copied the right client secret value.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!